# Not able to use Log android

Tags: java, android

I'm making about my 4th android app, and nothing that I try to log is showing up, I'm so confused. All my other apps will log things just fine, but this won't I think this is the error message for logging,
`ignoring message with no sender credentials`
Although I'm not sure, as it shows up alot. Here is what I'm doing to log.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("SMS", "testing");
}
```

I really don't understand what could be wrong. I've compared the application manifests with those of my other apps, and they don't seem to be different.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You see nothing in the logcat or just this log message?

Comment: @Rasel sorry should have specified, just the log message. All my other apps are able to print out log messages just fine.

Comment: But sometimes device changes for the log.So messages is not shown.Are you seeing log while launching the application?

Comment: @Rasel Yes I'm seeing the log, just not the messages the app is printing out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is kind of obvious isn't it?

The tag `SMS` is taken by the android native SMS application. Rename your tag and you'll have no problems.